# ListFragment does not show title bar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listfragment

Why title bar not show it in the `ListFragment`?

I did not set fullscreen or other.Please help me

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".CrimeListActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CrimePagerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

CrimeListFragment.java

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;
private static final String TAG = "CrimeListFragment";

private Crime c;
...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.crimes_title);
    mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();


    CrimeAdapter adapter = new CrimeAdapter(mCrimes);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ...
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add your code for referance

Comment: hard to guess without seeing the code, but did you maybe extend `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Check, if there isn't for example "AppTheme.NoActionBar" as your app theme at Design, in your fragment xml file.

Answer (score 0):

change the theme of your activity in manifest.

android:theme=""